# Updated app on Google developers console OPENGL differnt

Tags: android, opengl-es

[updated app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j96B5.png)

I updated my app and after upload the apk  system show the message in the picture. I translate from Greek to English the red text.
*Unable publication of this configuration for the following reasons:
Version 1 is not supported for any device configuration: all devices where you were taking the issue one will download version 2.*
I dont know why the updated apk has OPENGL version 1.0 the primary app has 2.0
Can anyone help !!!

Comment: check your manifest for opengl version

Comment: add this in manifest for openGL 2.0 `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="false"/>`

Comment: I add this to manifest,  now the updated apk has the same opengl version but the red text remains from the system. Thanks for your help Akshay Bhat